# Time based Eviction Policy in Apache Ignite

Tags: hazelcast, ignite

Like Hazelcast have Time based Eviction on Listener, Is there any such Policy in Apache's Ignite cache.

I tried,

```
setExpiryPolicyFactory(FactoryBuilder.factoryOf( new CreatedExpiryPolicy(new Duration(TimeUnit.SECONDS, 123))));
```

but it is Cache level Eviction, I need Entry level Eviction Statergy.

Can you suggest me any policy or any other way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
cache.withExpiryPolicy(new CreatedExpiryPolicy(new Duration(TimeUnit.SECONDS, 123))).put(k, v);
```

The expiration will be applied only to this entry.

Comment: Thank you. One More Thing to add. How can I emit the expired Entry on Particular Listener. Like in Hazelcast we can add Listener by HazelcastInstance.getMap().addEntryListener("_Some_Listener class"). Is there any way for Ignite Also.

Comment: Sounds like you can try continuous queries: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/continuous-queries

Comment: Hello Valentin. sorry for informing you Late it worked. Thank you.